# Custom Map View

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Here is the scenario...

I have a image of a map in jpeg format... I want to add it to my iPhone application and mark the coordinates in certain places (just like annotation in map kit ) and also when i move from one place to another place the current location should change and the new location should be marked in the image.
Is that possible ? How to achieve this instead of using the mkmapview ?

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial how to add custom google maps, maybe you could use your image (.jpeg) as a overlay.
[stiern.com/tutorials/adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website](http://stiern.com/tutorials/adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use an MKOverlay. 
Essentially it boils down to looking at the TileMap sample code from WWDC 2010. It'll still load the Google Map in the background and your map over the top